# How to make a table with 1 row by default

Tags: jsf-2

I have a table and I want that everytime I run the program it show 1 blank row by default. How can i do that?

```
<h:dataTable cellspacing="0" value="#{editQuestion.answersData}" var="answer">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{answer.answer.id}" />
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['admin.edit.rightanswer']}"  /></f:facet>
                        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{answer.answer.isRight}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="#{i18n['admin.edit.answers']}"  /></f:facet>
                        <h:inputTextarea id="answer" rows="3" cols="40" value="#{answer.text}" required="true" label ="Answer">
                            <f:validateLength maximum="500"/>
                        </h:inputTextarea>
                        <div>
                           <h:message for="answer" style ="color:red"/>  
                        </div>

                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <h:commandButton image="/resources/imgs/#{editQuestion.buttonDelete}" immediate ="true" action="#{editQuestion.deleteAnswer(answer)}" disabled="#{!editQuestion.possibleToDelete}" alt="delete" title="#{i18n['img.delete']}">
                            <f:param name="id" value="#{editQuestion.id}"/>
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a new instance of `Answer` to the list behind `#{editQuestion.answerData}` during the (post)construction of the bean behind `#{editQuestion}`.

E.g. during the postconstruct:

```
private List<Answer> answerData;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    answersData = new ArrayList<Answer>();
    answersData.add(new Answer());
}
```

Note that the bean needs to be `@ViewScoped` in order to preserve the right data across submits on the same view.